# wp e commerce other currency conversion at checkout

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress 3.4 and the WP E Commerce 3.8
Looked for the following functionality, but couldn't find quite the right answer. Hence I am trying my luck here. The plugin gives you the ability to provide a different price for a different currency. But at checkout, it is the base currency that is shown there. What I am looking for is :

- The shop will have a drop down to select options. (Like [fabindia](http://fabindia.com) web site)

a) Delivery within India 
b) International Delivery

- According to the selection the price is shown in INR (Delivery withing India) or in USD (International Delivery) IMPORTANT : The USD price is put manually, not converted from INR.
- If the International Delivery is selected, the prices in the checkout page will be the USD price converted into INR.

Example : (user selected International Delivery) 
          Product page and single product page : **Sandal Soap : USD 25** 
          Checkout page - list of products     : **Sandal Soap : USD 25**
                        - Amount payable       : INR **1,340.93** ($25 converted into INR at current rate)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I the answer I gave you in the [comments of my currency conversion plugin](http://haet.at/currency-assistant-pro/#comment-390) obviously didn't help you...
I think you should have a look at the wp-e-commerce-role-discount plugin. It adds an additional price field to the products page and reads the value of the field in the 'wpsc_top_of_products_page' hook. Maybe the [source code](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-e-commerce-role-discount/trunk/includes/class-haetrolediscount.php#L136)  can help you: Line 7 and Line 136 (and don't forget 156).
Instead of checking for isPremiumCustomer() you can check for "useInternationalPrice()" or sth. like that.

But this is only the first part of your problem. The second part is converting the USD price back to INR.
This can be done with a `wp_remote_get()` or curl to the google conversion API:
...google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD=?INR

Comment: Thank you, but most of this is going above my head. Can someone give me some more instruction as to achieve this? Or is there anyone who can do this for me? My client is ready to pay.